# Define elevator floors (symmetry, ordering) in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to specify an ordered set of floors in Alloy 6, so that I can later simulate an elevator visiting those floors.

Ultimately, I want to generate a graph that looks like the image below:

[image: how-to-navigate-between-floors]

Ideally, I could support any amount of floors more than two.

At first, I thought I should have an abstract set:

```
abstract sig Floor {}

sig MidFloor extends Floor {
    up : one Floor,
    down : one Floor
} {
    this not in up
    this not in down
    // cannot be above top floor
    up in Floor - TopFloor
    // cannot be below bottom floor
    down in Floor - BottomFloor
}

one sig TopFloor extends Floor {
    up : one Floor
} {
    this not in up
}

one sig BottomFloor extends Floor {
    down : one Floor
} {
    this not in down
}
```

But then I couldn't figure out how to further constrain the up/down relationships. So instead, I thought I would only use a single set:

```
sig Floor {
  up : lone Floor,
  down : lone Floor
}

one sig bottom, top in Floor {}

fact {
  no top.up
  no bottom.down
  // all floors are reachable from the bottom or the top
  Floor in bottom.*up
  Floor in top.*down
}
```

But then I couldn't figure out how to implement Up/Down symmetry. Where the set of

From either of these starting points, how do I get the desired graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might not even need to model it this way: you can use the [ordering module](https://alloy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/ordering.html):

```
open util/ordering[Floor]
sig Floor {}
```

Then the bottom floor is `first`, the bottom floor is `last`, up is `next`, and down is `prev`.

Unfortunately, you'll have trouble getting the layout you want, since Alloy's visualizer doesn't give you a lot of control over the specific layout of nodes. You can try laying out the down arrows backwards in the `Theme` option, but that only gets you so far.

I'd consider defining just one field, `up`, and then defining `down` as the reverse of `up`:

```
sig Floor {
  up : lone Floor,
}

one sig bottom, top in Floor {}

fun down: Floor -> Floor { ~up }
fact {
  no top.up
  Floor in bottom.*up
}
```